# jquery plugin form add slashes when send form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

i have a problem with jquery plugin form calle malsup , this plugin it´s for send forms with jquery by ajax

The problem it´s that when i send form and receive in other file for POST all values , always show slashes

**For example if i send by POST the value called :** Garden

**Finally i get this :** \'Garden\'

**My script it´s this :**

```
<script> 
function sendpageesc(idform)
{ 
jQuery('#'+idform).ajaxForm({ 
target:'#s_col_loader', 

success: function() 
{ 
jQuery('#s_col_loader').fadeIn('slow'); 
} 

}); 
}
</script>
```

I try use stripslashes with php for receive but continue to show this characters

I don´t know how i can fix this problem

Thank´s and regards

**MNORE INFO :**

(MY HTML CODE)

```
<script>
sendpageesc("formasearch1");
</script>
<form action="search.php?page=1" method="post" name="form1" id="formasearch1">
<input name="sel['country']" value="London" type="hidden">
<input name="paginationr_1" value="1" id="pagination_1" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: I add html code for send in the post , you can see in the end , thank´s for help

Comment: That helped, but I haven't had the same problem that you mentioned. It might have to do with your PHP. Can you post the PHP code as well?

Comment: [Here's what I have](http://plnkr.co/edit/wLRGssyMAAzigEttvW7y?p=preview) so far, but I can't reproduce the issue. Just update this with the PHP and I might be able to help.